# IAM permissions for accessing, viewing and modify filters on GCP API Metrics page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-iam

I am unable to find documentation to set the appropriate IAM permissions to a user to access, view and modify filters on this GCP API Metrics page:
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/metrics

[image: API Metrics Page]

Does anyone know how this can be done with the minimal permissions required? Or if there is a role to it that is finer-grained than owner/editor/viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen you shared is managed by the `Service Usage API`. To be able to access it, you need the `serviceusage.services.get` permission which is part of the `Service Usage Viewer (roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageViewer)` role.

Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control) for further details about the service usage access controls.